# Always getting 0 after converting int to string

Tags: c++

I have a function for converting integers into std::string.

```
std::stringstream Tools::toStringConverter;
std::string Tools::tempString;

std::string Tools::intToString(int num) {
    toStringConverter.str(std::string());
    toStringConverter << num;
    toStringConverter >> tempString;
    return tempString;
}
```

When I try to use this method while using iterators, I get correct result

```
for(Button b : buttons) {
    std::cout << Tools::intToString(b.id);
}
```

Also output is correct if I try this:

```
std::cout<< intToString(3);
```

But when I use simple `for` loop, I always get 0.

```
for(int i = 0; i < NetworkManager::MAX_PLAYERS; i++) {
    std::cout << Tools::intToString(i) << " ";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)?

Comment: I get to_string is not a member of std

Comment: Are you compiling with the `-std=c++11` compiler flag set? Did you include the appropriate header?

Comment: Yes, i do. And i have <string> included

Comment: Well, it works just fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3016f24448cad08) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string Tools::intToString(int num) {
    std::stringstream toStringConverter;
    toStringConverter << num;
    return toStringConverter.str();
}
```

Don't use global variables.

Comment: Wow! It worked for me. Thanks. I dont understand why using global variables caused it.